# How to Edit Post-Processing Through Script in Latest Unity Version

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing

I am trying to edit post processing in the latest unity urp. How would i go about this. I am aware of the other questions about this, however they are depreciated and are no longer working. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will have to use `Volume` component on an empty game object. There you can assign you own custom profile or clone existing profile. Also you must have to enable `Post Processing` in your current camera.

Comment: Please add your code or what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Use the Post Processing Stack v2. Add it through Window -> Package Manager. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.postprocessing.html